# LDAP with PHP - Get all groups for a specific member including full DN of the group

Tags: php, filter, ldap

I have this query in my application to get all groups from an LDAP-Server where a specific user is a member. Is it possible to change or extend this ldap_search() query to also return the full DN of the groups it finds?

```
ldap_search($conn, null, '(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member='.$searchUser.'))', array('cn'));
```

Or is the only way to achieve this to do an ldap_get_dn() for each returned result?

I have already tried to add 'dn' to the attributes array but that's always empty in the result set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess there is no other way of doing this then.

First do an `ldap_serach` like this:
`ldap_search($conn, null, '(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member='.$searchUser.'))', array('cn'));`

and then go through all the results and do an `ldap_get_dn()` for each to get the full `dn`.

Answer (score 1):

All search results contain the distinguished names of entries that matched the search parameters.

Comment: Thanks but the query above only returns the 'cn' of the groups that the user is a member of. 
How can I get the complete DN of the group? I tried adding 'dn' to the attributes array but that's always empty.
Any ideas?